# wpf textbox databinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, datacontext

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0">Gangnam</TextBox>
      <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

In the code-behind I set a `datacontext` for `myGrid`. I'm also planning to make a `datatemplate` to handle the `visualisation`.

For now, I would expect the `textbox` to contain the `typename` of my `class`, but instead there is a *`xml` parse exception ("Two-way binding requires Path or `XPath`.")*

This is how I set the `datacontext` on the control:

```
public LeftColumn()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      LeftColumnData dataObjectLeft = new LeftColumnData();
      myGrid.DataContext = dataObjectLeft;
    }
```

Comment: Try out removing `<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0">Gangnam</TextBox>
`

Comment: no effect ... btw, I just checked what the exception was and it says: "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."

Comment: What's the error?  Show how your are setting the datacontext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the DataContext is of type `LeftColumnData` and a TextBox uses Two-Way binding by default, it is impossible for the runtime to figure out the conversion between `String` and your datatype.

You can either try setting the binding to `OneWay`:

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" />
```

or implement an `IValueConverter` to handle the conversion:

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding, Converter={My:Converter}}" Grid.Column="1" />
```